# Forge Viewer poor rendering quality

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm using the Forge Viewer to display some models converted from IFC (2x3) files.
For some of them, the quality is perfect, but for others the rendering is very poor like the picture bellow.
[image: Weird forge rendering]

I've tried to export in SVF, SVF2 and same result.
I've tired different settings to load the model

```js
let config = {
    keepCurrentModels: true,
    applyScaling: { to: "m" },
    applyRefPoint: true,
    globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }}; //make the view flicker on weird rendered model
```

None of those settings improved the view except globalOffset who makes the view flicker.

Have you any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of deformation of geometries is typically an indication that the model is very far from the origin. So far that the GPU rendering starts running into floating point precision issues.

Loading the model with `globalOffset: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)` should help in this case as it would basically force the viewer not to re-apply the original global offset (which is potentially very large) to all geometry vertices. I'm not sure why the view would flicker after using this option, though, that might be a separate issue.

Comment: When I set globalOffset: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), the model flicker and stay with the same weird render. There is no improvement. I'll keep digging on the coordinates to see if I got any improvements

Comment: I'm also wondering if the `applyRefPoint` is somehow overriding the emptied global offset parameter. Try removing that one also.

Comment: Could you try the alignment `Origin to origin` of this tool to see if your IFC models aligned well? 

https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil#supported-alignments

Comment: It's working now ! I've edit my IFC file manually to check and update the coordinate of the IFCSITE. The viewer is now working well ! Thank you all